# How to delete other duplicate column names when merge two similar datasets by a specific column name in R

Tags: r

There are two large datasets each has more than 50 variables and they share lots of duplicate variables, say 6 duplicate variables: `ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5` and `houseID`. When merged the two datasets together by "`houseID`", 
`mergeAll <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by = "houseID")`,
other duplicate variables will change names, such as `ID1` in `dataset1` becomes `ID1.x`, and `ID1` in `dataset2` becomes `ID1.y`; However, they are the same, we only want to keep one of them and better do not change their name. At last, we want to create a master dataset without duplicate variables, but with all the information in `dataset1` and `dataset2`. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You can use `merge` but just delete the same named columuns from the second dataset.

```
# Preparing simulation
dataset1 <- as.data.frame(
  matrix(
    c(1:7, rnorm(7 * 40)), byrow = FALSE, 
    ncol = 41, dimnames = list(
      NULL, c("house_ID", paste0("ID", 1:5), paste0("D", 1:35)
      )
    )
  )
)


dataset2 <- as.data.frame(
  matrix(
    c(1:10, rnorm(10 * 50)), byrow = FALSE,
    ncol = 51, dimnames = list(
      NULL,  c("house_ID", paste0("ID", 1:5), paste0("E", 1:45)
      )
    )
  )
)


# Merging
excl_cols <- names(dataset2) %in% paste0("ID", 1:5)
res <- merge(dataset1, dataset2[, !excl_cols])
res
```

Comment: res <- merge(datset1, datset2)  , only works when two datasets have same rows. If dataset 1 has 10 and dataset2 has 7 rows, they should only have 7 matched rows based on house_ID which is the common identifier. And, although ID1....ID6 have the same variable names, the values might be different due to error. We only want to keep the variable names and values in dataset1 and delete duplicate variable names and values in dataset2. How to do it?  In SAS, they have code to do that: proc sql; create table test2 as select * from ph.combevents as a left join baseline as b on a.id = b.id;